# Scala pattern match on the type of two bind variables

Tags: scala

I have two variables of unknown type. I want to do a pattern match on the combination of the variable types, and then take action based on that -- specifically, I want to implement `Comparator[Any]` and compare the two variables based on their type. This code produces the desired result:

```scala
class SomethingComparator extends util.Comparator[Any] {
  override def compare(o1: Any, o2: Any) = List(o1, o2).map(_.isInstanceOf[Something]) match {
    case List(true, true) => o1.asInstanceOf[Something].someInt.compareTo(o2.asInstanceOf[Something].someInt)
    case List(true, false) => -1
    case List(false, true) => 1
    case _ => 0
  }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the `map` call and pattern match on the types directly, and therefore avoid the two `asInstanceOf` calls in the first match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```scala
class SomethingComparator extends util.Comparator[Any] {
  override def compare(o1: Any, o2: Any) = (o1, o2) match {
    case (o1:Something, o2:Something) => o1.someInt.compareTo(o2.someInt)
    case (o1:Something, o2:Any) => -1
    case (o1:Any, o2:Something) => 1
    case _ => 0
  }
}
```

Comment: You were getting the "unreachable code" error because the second and third `case`s are the same.  The `o1` and `o2` in the `case` are bound by the match, so they are treated as new variables, not the same as the old `o1` and `o2`.

Comment: Thx, just figured that out :)